# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!) = (n+1)! - 1$ by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> How do you prove this using induction? 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!) = (n+1)! - 1$$
>   for all positive integers n

Base Case: $1(1!) = 1$ and $(2!) - 1 = 1$, so this works for$ n = 1$.

How do I show the $n + 1$ case?

Comment: Have you at least done the basis step? Have you written out what you must show in the inductive step? You should show what you already know about proving an identity by induction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Do you require using induction? There's a different shorter & easier way I see to prove it instead. Regardless, as John Wayland Bales asked & requested, please first show what you've already tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k ~ k!= \sum_{k=0}^{n} [(k+1) -1]~ k!= \sum_{k=0}^{n}[(k+1)!- k!]=(n+1)!-1.$$ In the last step we have done telescoping summation.

Comment: +1 - I was just finishing writing basically the same answer as you when I saw your answer come in.

Comment: John Omielan It is just that my fingers were fast  Wish you better luck for the next time..

Comment: Thanks for the wish for better luck next time. Note that in addition to your fast fingers, another factor is I waited a while for the OP to respond to my question comment, or at least show something of what they've already tried, before I started typing.

Answer (score 4):

Actually using induction.

If
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!) = (n+1)! - 1
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k!)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!)+(n+1)(n+1)!\\
&=(n+1)! - 1+(n+1)(n+1)!\\
&=(n+2)(n+1)!-1\\
&=(n+2)!-1\\
\end{array}\\
$

which is what you want to prove.

Comment: Might be a bad question. How do you get to (+2)(+1)!−1? I'm not really sure where the 2 comes from. Thanks.

Comment: $a+(n+1)a = (n+2)a$. Apply this to $a=(n+1)!$. Then $(n+2)(n+1)! = (n+2)!$.

Comment: I meant the part where (+1)!−1+(+1)(+1)! = (+2)(+1)!−1. I get the minus 1, but why is (+1)! +(+1)(+1)!  = (+2)(+1)!. Thanks.

Comment: Treat $(n+1)! =A$ as a solid chunk and factor it out: $A - 1 + (n+1)A = (n+1)A + A - 1 = A((n+1) + 1) -1 = A(n+2)-1$

Comment: Look at my previous comment again.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!) = (n+1)! - 1$

Then $(n+1)(n+1)! + \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!) = (n+1)(n+1)! + (n+1)! -1 $

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k!)= (n+1)![(n+1) + 1] - 1= (n+1)!(n+2)-1 =(n+2)! - 1$